# Could'nt open the Html Page, instead Download the file

Tags: java, servlets

I am new on servlet.i have made # clases(Login,Logout,Profile).A simple error that i not solved.A link passes to call the all classes.Login and Logout work properly bt when i click on profile , it will show Downloaded file option.Please help Me , Tnkx in advance.

**Logout.java**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);

    Cookie ck=new Cookie("uername", "");
    ck.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(ck);
    out.print("you are successfully logged out!");
```

**Login.java**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);

        String username=request.getParameter("name");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");

        if(username.equals("pr"))
        {
              out.print("You are successfully logged in!");  
                out.print("<br>Welcome, "+username);

              Cookie ck=new Cookie(username, username);  
              response.addCookie(ck);

        }
        else{  
            out.print("sorry, username or password error!");  
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);  
        }  
        out.close();
 }
```

**Profile.java**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("html/text");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);

        Cookie ck[]=request.getCookies();
        System.out.println(ck[0].getValue());

        if(ck!=null)
        {
            String name=ck[0].getValue();

             if(!name.equals(null)||name!=null)
             {
                 out.print("<b>Welcome to Profile</b>");  
                 out.print("<br>Welcome, "+name);   
             }
         }
        else{  
            out.print("Please login first");  
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);  
        }  
        out.close(); 

    }
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">  

  <servlet>  
    <description></description>  
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>  
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.servletcookie.LoginServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet>  
    <description></description>  
    <display-name>ProfileServlet</display-name>  
    <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.servletcookie.ProfileServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>ProfileServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/ProfileServlet</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet>  
    <description></description>  
    <display-name>LogoutServlet</display-name>  
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.servletcookie.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <!-- <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> -->
</web-app>
```

Comment: Which webserver are you running this on?

Comment: i used ApacheTomcat for server and Eclipe for IDE

Comment: What do you mean by "click profile" - which page allows you to do that?

Comment: @jens Krogsboell ,i have made link<a href> tag and when i click login , it will run bt not in case of profile

Comment: @JensKrogsboell ,  same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.setContentType("html/text");
```

should be

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

Comment: Yup , your answer is right for my silly mistake bt can this happens if we changed it because they are in the  double qoute.

Comment: Yes - literal string values cannot be checked at compile time - you just have to get them right:-)